# requireActivity().getApplicationContext() "may produce a NullPointerExeption"

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

Bellow there is some of the code of my application. The part where I need help is in `requireActivity()` in SettingFragment.java:

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
   }

   public void iniciarIntent3() {   //this method is called by a button in activity_main.xml
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   }
}
```

**Settings.java**

```
...

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity implements SettingsFragment.SendToActivity {
   ...
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
      if (fragment instanceof SettingsFragment) {
         SettingsFragment settingsFragment = (SettingsFragment) fragment;
         settingsFragment.setSendToActivity(this);
      }
   }
   public void send(int result) {
      ...
   }
}
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

   SendToActivity callback;

   public void setSendToActivity (SendToActivity callback) {
      this.callback = callback;
   }

   public interface SendToActivity {
      void send(int result);
   }
   
   if (editTextPreference != null) {
      editTextPreference.setOnBindEditTextListener(new 
      EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
         @Override
         public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            editText.setText("");                
            editText.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireActivity()
               .getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.fondo_edittextpreference));
         }
      });
   }
   ...
}
```

I just want to be sure that `requireActivity()` in SettingsFragment class is not going to throw a nullpointerexeption. Can you help me to check?

Comment: It depends entirely on the state of the fragment at the time you execute the `requireActivity()` call and whether it is attached to an activity or not at the time. You could eliminate the `requireActivity()` call by using [`setBackgroundResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#setbackgroundresource), or by getting a `Context` from the `EditText`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Right, I'm gonna use `setBackgroundResource()`. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

requireActivity()

can throw null if the Activity is null for whatever reason that may be.
I believe that can be null if the user exists the application or forefully stops it etc. Or there was never one created in the context that youre in

Just do a try-catch

```
Activity activity;
try {
    activity = requireActivity()
    editText.setBackground(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            activity.getApplicationContext(),
            R.drawable.fondo_edittextpreference));
} catch (NullPointerException orTypeOfException) {
    //handle here when the activity is null
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: This is flawed. `requireActivity()` will throw an exception, but never return null. The else would never be reached, because the app would crash.

Comment: As @Michiel has said, the point of `requireActivity()` will never be null. Usually it is used for inline usages where you don't want lint to litter your IDE with warnings.  Generally speaking if you need the activity and its null then the logic is probably flawed and should throw an unrecoverable error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `requireActivity().getApplicationContext()` you could do either of the following

1. `editText.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(editText.getContext(), R.drawable.fondo_edittextpreference))`
2. `editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondo_edittextpreference)`